# Wordpress does not have the permission to update (IspConfig)

Tags: permissions

When I try to update a Wordpress website on a server I do not `own` since it is from an hosting provider. I am getting an error I never had.

[image]

Translated to English (it is Dutch)

```
Download update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/nl_NL/wordpress-5.4.1.zip…

The authenticity of wordpress-5.4.1.zip could not be verified because no signature was found.

Unpacking update…

Cannot copy file: wordpress/wp-includes/capabilities.php

Installation failed
```

I have chmod all folders to `755` and all files to `655`. But when I look at the file and folder I see. `wordpress/wp-includes/capabilities.php`

But when I look in my Filezilla, this folder don't seems to exist at all (or I cannot find this)

[image]

Now I was wondering if this is due to certain permissions (chown). Or that the zip file (from Wordpress) is placed incorrectly (and how I can find that out). I have never encountered this problem before.

Comment: "all files to 655" - you probably meant 644, i.e. not executable. But the 6 only works if the file ownership is correct: can you check that the user that owns that file is the web server user, presumably user ID 5565? (but possibly 535 - who are these users?)

Comment: Alternatively if you can get a shell terminal on the server I'd just unpack the latest WordPress myself from that.